# Working with jQuery Slider - positions

Tags: jquery, slider

I have been working with the slider and am using the following code:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#slider').slider({
            animate: true,
            step: 1,
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            orientation: 'vertical',
            start: function(event, ui){
                $('#current_value').empty();
                $('#current_value').fadeIn().append('Value is ' + ui.value);
            },
            change: function(event, ui){
                alert();
                //$('#current_value').empty();
            }

        });
    });
```

I am trying to get it for at the top it is a value of 10 and the bottom is a value of 1 and step 1. Does that look correct?

The other problem I am having is when you move from one position to another, I want it to show the position it stopped on (the current).

So if it is at 4 and you click 7, when you stop append to the DIV I tried changed and stop, but it isnt behaving that way. It is taking the wrong position value.

**Link**: http://www.ryancoughlin.com/demos/interactive-slider/index.html
if you use the keyboard and go to the bottom my goal is to have it step from 1 to 10 in 1 increments

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your CHANGE event with SLIDE ... i've asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621147/jquery-ui-slider-cant-slide-to-0) a while ago.

you might want to add STOP event as well ... move your logic from START to SLIDE and STOP

Comment: I just took another look at the docs and found that SLIDE works perfect..thank you