# HTML5 Range Sliders w/ jQuery occasionally not going to full max or min values

Tags: jquery, html, input, range

I have a fairly simple form with a single HTML5 range element in it (being rendered as a slider).  The code for that looks like this:

```
<form name="redform" id="redform" action="/">
    <input id="id"        name="id"        type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
    <input id="sliderRed" name="sliderRed" type="range"  value="<?php echo $data[5]; ?>" min="0" max="255" />
</form>
<p class="note">Current value: <span id="redValue">0</span></p>
<div style="text-align:center; color:#FF0000" id="redresults"></div>
```

Accompanying this is some jQuery that executes an external php script whenever the slider is moved:

```
$(function(){
    var redValue = $('#redValue');
    $('#sliderRed').change(function(){
        redValue.html(this.value);
    }); 
    $('#sliderRed').mouseup(function(){
        $.post('process.php',  $("#redform").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#redresults').html(data);
            $('#redresults').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
    $('#sliderRed').change();
});
```

All of that works.  I can move the slider around, the value updates live, and the PHP script is run when the slider is released.  Here's what's weird.  The max and min values for the range slider are set to 0 and 255. However, sometimes, when dragging the slider all the way to one end, it will only hit 1 or 254.  There doesn't seem to be any pattern to when this happens.  Sometimes it goes to the full range, sometimes it can't go all the way.  This is even the case while keeping you mouse held down and dragging it back and forth.

If the max and min are changed to 256 and -1 respectively, similar behavior is observed.  Sometimes it will max out at 256, and sometimes it will max out at 255.  On the bottom end, it will sometimes hit -1, and sometimes it can only be dragged down to 0.  This indicates to me that it doesn't have to do with actual numbers, but with some weird "off-by-one" bug.

Any thoughts on this?  I'm totally stumped...

Comment: its working fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/AMAVB/ but sometimes it bugs :/

Comment: If sometimes it bugs, then by definition it's not working fine.  I experience the same issue in the jsfiddle you posted.  Sometimes it can only be dragged to 1 or 254.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the suggestions provided are great (thanks Jason). It's worth explaining why this issue actually occurs.  I submitted this as a bug to the chromium bug tracker thinking it might be a chrome bug.  I was half right.  See the post here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171362

The issue is that if the slider is not at least 256 pixels long, then it's impossible for all the values to be selectable.  Using CSS, you can change the width to 256px, which eliminates the issue I described in my question.

```
<input id="sliderRed" name="sliderRed" stlye="width:256px;" type="range"  value="<?php echo $data[5]; ?>" min="0" max="255" />
```

However, this limitation makes using jQuery-UI a preferred solution, and what I will probably end up implementing.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the [slider object in jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) and the "stop" object for better performance. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621147/jquery-ui-slider-cant-slide-to-0).

Comment: I'd prefer to define the slider in the html since I'm pulling in an initial value via PHP.

Comment: You could initialize it with something along the lines of `$( ".selector" ).slider({ value: <?php echo $data[5]; ?> });`

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout() to delay execution of your mouseup callback by 10 milliseconds or so.

**Update**:

To clarify, the following code should work. I've had this same problem before, and setting a small delay resolved the issue. (Upon further reflection, I don't recall the precise duration of the delay required; you might increase the delay value if you implement this code and the problem persists.)

```
$('#sliderRed').mouseup(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.post('process.php',  $("#redform").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#redresults').html(data);
            $('#redresults').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
        });
    }, 10);
});
```

Comment: Thanks - Sorry for my ignorance, but where would I actually put that function?

Comment: I added the timeout before the $.post and it didn't help.

Comment: See my answer below - this ends up being a workaround for how chromium is dealing with sliders that are smaller than the range requested.